# Write a regular expression based named entity recognition module (NER)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am new to Python and just started using it with NLP, I need to write a regular expression based named entity recognition module.
Anyone provide me with helpful links or examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org), a NLP platform for python, especially the Named Entity Recognition Chunker (NER Chunker). Chunkers can be constructed using the RegexpParser class.

There is a free online book, and [chapter 7 has detailed explanations and code examples.](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#sec-ner)

Comment: Thank you very much. I already studied this it talks about using NLTK ne_chunk, but I need to extract the NEs from any text  using regular expression.